# How to animate the text color of a QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidgetitem

I'm trying to implement some flashing (any kind of short highlighting) for a `QTableWidgetItem`. `QPropertyAnimation` apparently can't be used here, because `QTableWidgetItem` seems to be no derivate of `QObject`.

Is there a convenient way to implement a fading effect for a QTableWidgetItem?

Comment: The widget you probably want to animate is its [cellWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellWidget).

Comment: cellWidget gives me a nullptr for all displayed cells …